# Video error when trying to download the src

Tags: javascript, html

I used HTML `<video>` tags to display videos. Getting the source through vimeo.

It works once every 10 tries. I have no idea why. Is it only a problem of network? The problem is even more severe on Safari.

[image]

I've tried changing the `src` links to local videos.